# Widget settings hook for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

What hook is the equivalent in Drupal 7 for `hook_widget_settings($op, $widget)`, used in Drupal 6?

What hook is the equivalent in Drupal 7 for `hook_widget_settings_save()`, used in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_field_widget_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7).

Here you can give the widget settings.

Comment: Also the Examples project has a sample field implementation with some settings. http://drupal.org/project/examples